# Reading huge text files in MATLAB line by line

Tags: matlab, large-files

I have an ASCII file which has fixed width columns (all rows are 68 characters - bytes - long).

I wrote the typical while loop in MATLAB to read the file line by line. All I want to do is compare one line to the previous one, so I use `fgetl` and `sscanf` to extract what I need. The loop breaks when the result of fgetl is not a string (`~ischar`).

After testing it on two files (4.1 GB and 30.9 GB) I found that the loop stops exactly when 4 GB has been read (number of lines times 68 bytes).

This is MATLAB r2012b x64 running on Windows 7 x64. What gives?

EDIT:

Actual code:

```
fid = fopen('hugefile.txt', 'r');
oldtime = -1;
counter = 0;
timejumps = [];
while 1
  line = fgetl(fid);
  if ~ischar(line), break, end
  counter = counter+1;
  %progress indicator
  if mod(counter, 100000) == 0, fprintf('At line %d...\n', counter); end
  A = sscanf(line, '%d %*f %d %*d %*d %*f %*f');
  newtime = A(1)+A(2)/1000;
  if newtime < oldtime
    fprintf(1, 'Illegal time jump from %f to %f at line %d.\n', ...
      oldtime, newtime, counter);
    timejumps = [timejumps; counter, oldtime, newtime];
  end
  oldtime = newtime;
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: You should post the code you are using.

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is, but if you're wondering why it stopped after processing 4GB rather than 4.1GB, it may be because you're not accounting for carriage returns and/or line breaks.

Comment: Or is it stopping at 4GB on the 30.9GB file also?

Comment: @Charles: it stops just short of 4 GB on both files. It stops just short because 4 GB = 4,294,967,296 bytes which is not divisible by 68. So the attempt to `fgetl` the line that would make it read past 4 GB returns `-1` and thus breaks out of the loop. As you can see it is not a RAM issue since I'm not keeping anything significant in RAM. Seems to be a 32 bit limit, but why?

Comment: Are you able to fseek past that point (to, say, 8GB) in the big file and read a line?

Answer (score 1):

However it is really hard to say without any further information but I think you are saving result of comparing two lines separately, which means you have an array that increases the size until reaches your memory limit.
(I would've comment this but since my reputation is not enough I have to post it as an answer)